# SSVI parametrization motivation , SSVI implementation

Tags: volatility-smile, volatility-surface

I've read the following paper of Gatheral and Jacquier https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0646.pdf about volatility surfaces. I'm thinking about the SSVI surface. Is there any motivation why they choose exactly this parameterization? 
Moreover I had a look at this https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/cfm-imperial-institute-of-quantitative-finance/events/distinguished-lectures/Gatheral-2nd-Lecture.pdf. On page 17 he writes that: This smile is completely defined given three observables.
The ATM volatility and ATM skew are obvious choices for two of them.
The most obvious choice for the third observable in equity markets would be the asymptotic slope for negative and in FX markets and interest rate markets, perhaps the ATM curvature of the smile might be more appropriate. Does these mean I need this data for calibrating SSVI? 
And then when Implementing he does this in a quite complicated way, it seems to me. Is there an easier method?
And if I fix $\theta=\theta_t$ and plot $\omega(k,\theta)$ I should have a smile? Am I right? Because I only get a line. For $\phi$ I used the heston like function. Can maybe anybody tell me values for $\rho$ and $\lambda$ to get a curve, so I can see this is possible with this parameterization. 
Thanks in advance!

---

Update 
Something with my update doesn't work. So I have given these data:
k=[ -0.0193, -0.0070, 0.0040, 0.0150, 0.0260]
implied volatility= [0.0366, 0.0331, 0.0320, 0.0329, 0.0344]
t=0.25. So total implied variance=0.25*(implied volatility)^2.
By interpolation I can find $\theta_t=3.0000e-04$
Now my program gives me $\rho=-0.9993, \lambda=3.8324$. If I plot this it looks like the file attached. Can anybody tell me where I made a mistake?[image]

Answer (score 1):

In short no you don't need to estimate the values for these quantities to calibrate the model. Instead what you want to do is to perform a least squares optimization on the model parameters against market volatilities, this gives you the calibrated surface to the market prices and if you want to output the model quantities you mentioned then you can.

So you want to minimise the error between

$$\sigma_{model} = \sqrt{w(k,\theta_t;t)/t}$$ and $$\sigma_{market}(k,t)$$ as

$$\sum_{k, t} |\sigma_{model}(k, \theta_t;t) - \sigma_{market}(k,t)|^2 < \epsilon$$

for some $\epsilon >0$. You will either have quotes from the market in terms of prices or volatilites, if you have prices then you must use a numerical method such as Newton-Raphson to obtain the market volatilities. During the optimisation procedure you will need to enforce the constraints mentioned in the paper.

Comment: I tried to do this. But instead of a curve I only get a line. My try now was to begin with minimizing the market volatilites agains the model volatilities. Then I used the calibrated parameters to determine the jumpwing parametrization and this lead to an better approximation, but its quite complicated.  And is my understanding right, that $\omega(k,\theta_t)$ and the raw parametrization $\omega(k,\chi_R)$ or the jumpwing parametrization describe the same smile?

Comment: I’m a little unsure how you get a flat smile, could you post some plots? You can just work directly with the Heston parametrisation in the SSVI rather than in one of the reparametrisations of the SVI model. Your $\theta_t$ Should be the total ATM BS variance right? This should be an input rather than something calibrated to.

Comment: I have updatet my question and attached a plot

Comment: I noticed when you posted the update on my post you had something like $1.0e-3 * 0.26...$ type "total volatilities" but your new update on your post has different numbers, the original ones seemed more like equity style implied vols at level around 0.26 but I was unsure where the other multiplicative factor came from. Because your $\theta_t$ is so low, your optimiser is finding a solution with $~\rho=-1.0$ which gives a straight line.

Comment: As an example if I interpolate to find the implied vol corresponding to $k=0$ as $\sigma_{ATM}=0.26$, I would expect my total ATM variance $\theta_{0.25}=0.25*0.26*0.26=0.0169$. If you try plotting with sensible params ($\rho=-0.7, \lambda = 0.5$), you should get a nice smile. Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: But shouldn't the interpolated $\sigma_{ATM}$ be between 0.0331 and 0.0320?

Comment: What is your underlying? An equity? Can you give the information required to invert the prices to implied vols? Premium, forward, spot, discount factor, maturity etc. It looks like your "implied vols" array values are very low. Technically it should be possible with these values, it could be that your choice of optimisation is producing a local minima/fails to find a solution as your $\rho$ is essentially $-1$.

Comment: I got these data as input from another person. So do you think that the mistake is in the data?

Comment: It could well be. Try some artificial numbers that produce a smile around the 0.23 level, it should confirm if you can produce a calibrated smile or not. If you still have an issue then you probably need to check your constrained optimisation and check that the routine isn’t reaching a local minima. You could also try the power law implementation instead of the Heston one in the same paper, I think you get an extra parameter with that one.

Comment: The implied vols and the log moneyness look wrong. 3% vol is in deed very low. And then the log-moneyness is also very close to 0, with a maximum of 2%. Well for a maturity of 3 months, this is extremely narrow.  At least it's somewhat consistent with such a low vol, but this begs the question: what is the underlying asset?